# Is there a shared error interface for network certificate errors?

Tags: go, ssl, networking, error-handling

I've been trying to find a shared interface in Go's standard library which is used for all tls/certificate errors.[1](https://go.dev/src/crypto/)

What I have in mind is something like what we have for timeout errors which any error that is a timeout error shares the following interface.

```golang
type timeout interface{
  Timeout() bool
}
```

I wonder if it even exists.

**Update:** What I want to be able to is to perform a check like this:

```
type TLSErr interface{
  CertError() bool
}

resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)

var tlsErr TLSError
if errors.As(err, &tlsErr) && tlsErr.CertError(){
  // perform some specific logic
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what you want to do? All returned errors share the same interface, the Error interface containing function Error().

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I included an example in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, by browsing the go code of crypto libs, it seems that errors.New("") is used a lot in the libraries, and I can't see any pattern in the error string (except sometimes prefixed by "crypto/"). Maybe in the httpClient.Do() function, there is a special error returned when manipulating certificate?

Comment: Does `tls.Config` not contain the point at which you want to track an error? It contains various callbacks at specific points in TLS negotiation in which you can handle errors